# How to implement :selected state with TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I read the documentation but I don't find anything about the `:selected` state in Tailwind CSS. Is there a way to achieve this with Tailwind or it can be only done with JavaScript?

I simplified the problem as much as possible, If the radio button is checked I want to change the parent div's color

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <div class="flex items-center mb-4 focus:bg-blue-100">
        <input id="default-radio-1" type="radio" value="" selected name="default-radio" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
        <label for="default-radio-1" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Default radio</label>
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center mb-4 active:bg-blue-100">
        <input checked id="default-radio-2" type="radio" value="" name="default-radio" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
        <label for="default-radio-2" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Checked state</label>
    </div>
```

If I use the `active` state I reach my goal, but only for a few seconds. I also can`t find other way to achieve this in AlpineJS.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So far, the answers are assuming you are referring to the "checked" state, since your code uses radio buttons. The "selected" state/attribute is used in a dropdown's `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tailwind it is not possible to style the parent based on the child that is checked, but with [this part of the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) you are able to put different styles on an element AFTER a checked input. It requires the `peer` class on the input and the `peer-checked:` prefix for classes that you want to apply when the input has been checked.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex items-center mb-4 focus:bg-blue-100">
  <input id="default-radio-1" type="radio" value="" selected name="default-radio" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 peer">
  <label for="default-radio-1" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300  peer-checked:bg-red-300 peer-checked:text-white">Default radio</label>
</div>
<div class="flex items-center mb-4 active:bg-blue-100">
  <input checked id="default-radio-2" type="radio" value="" name="default-radio" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
  <label for="default-radio-2" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Checked state</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what i want, but I can solve the problem with it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind CSS does not implement the `:has()` pseudo-selector yet (it's not supported in Firefox). You can still use it in your CSS file though. For example:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

@layer components {
  div:has(input:checked) {
    @apply bg-red-500;
  }
}

@tailwind utilities;
```

You can see a working version of this here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/VHMr7KnWjN